# Save Javascript Data (JSON) into database

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a table as you can see in the Link here: http://csgo.nssgaming.com/index.php
This is a list with data there is automatic updated, but instead of outputting this information in a table, i would like to have it into a database. but i have no idea how to do it, when it is in javascript. so i would be happy if someone could tell me what to do or show a example.

you can see the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Install gentoo fgt -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>csgolounge-api example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="http://bootswatch.com/darkly/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">lel</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="well" id="radio_2">
                        <legend>Matches</legend>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Team_1</th>
                                    <th>Team_2</th>
                                    <th>Time</th>
                                    <th>Status</th>
                                    <th>Link->csgolounge</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function sortTable(table, order) {
            var asc   = order === 'asc',
                tbody = table.find('tbody');

            tbody.find('tr').sort(function(a, b) {
                if (asc) return $('td:last', a).text().localeCompare($('td:last', b).text());
                else return $('td:last', b).text().localeCompare($('td:last', a).text());
            }).appendTo(tbody);
        }

        $.getJSON("./api.php", function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                var live, time, team_1, team_2

                live = val.live
                time = val.time
                team_1 = val.teams[0].name + " (" + val.teams[0].percent + ")"
                team_2 = val.teams[1].name + " (" + val.teams[1].percent + ")"
                link = key
                status = live ? "Live" : ""

                if(val.result)
                    if(val.result.status == "won")
                        if(val.result.team == 0) team_1 += " [won]"
                        else team_2 += " [won]"

                $("tbody").html($("tbody").html() + "<tr><td>" + team_1 + "</td><td>" + team_2 + "</td><td>" + time + "</td><td>" + status + "</td><td>" + link + "</td></tr>")
                });

            sortTable($('table'),'desc');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: it is updated! thanks for the quick comment

Comment: What sort of database do you want to put it in?

Comment: Mysql i guess you can see the db structure here: https://gist.github.com/kris914g/dd678afb351234344993

Comment: MySQL doesn't run in the browser. If you want to put data into it then you need something running on the server. Isn't the data already in a database though? You're requesting a local URL (api.php).

Comment: The data is from a Json String and is going to be loaded when someone is loading the page, but i could make a cronjob i guess

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a whole lot of point in loading (what appears to be) a blank page into a browser to do a database operation. Even if you wanted to trigger it through a browser, you could do the whole this in PHP and not involve JS at all.

Comment: okay, but what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You mean you got data from the [API](http://csgo.nssgaming.com/api.php) and you would like to save it in you database?

Then, instead of $.getJSON, you can use $.ajax. It makes you able to send the data. It will forward data to your database.

```
$.getJSON("./api.php", function(data) {

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    method : "POST",
    url: 'database.php',
    data: data,
    success: function(){
      console.log('Data has been sent to the server!')
    }
  });

  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    //... fill your table ... 
  });
  sortTable($('table'),'desc');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the Quick Answer i think you are right! but how can put those values into the tables? i already tables as you can see here:                         https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1kuTLsmBdTq2NI5B6D8Ox5AmHBZk5kMR4qV6hXHSzTYE/edit?usp=sharing                                                                                                         But am i going to make a variable in php? or how does it work when it is Ajax?

Comment: First you need a database. It could be MySQL for example. Then, you can make request via some 'helpers' like msqli : [W3School on MySQL & PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/kris914g/57710e47cddc3dbc271f                                   I am not great to use Ajax but how am i going to get the values from the table into the database?

Comment: You will just forward "data". 

Then in the PHP, connect to you database.

Comment: what do you mean with "Forward Data" could you show a simple example  so i can't understand? i have never worked with ajax an javascript before.

Comment: I already did, the "ajax" part is ended. Create a database.php file. You will get data in the $_POST variable or $_GET depending on the method option of the $.ajax method. You have to choose your database now.

Comment: Okay so if i use mysql, is it still posssiple to do with PDO`?

Comment: this is what i got so far. https://gist.github.com/kris914g/528e529a04f90035bd45 it is just a example but how can i get this work in my case?

Comment: Same code, but you should learn MySQL, then use JSON_decode to transform the request to php object (on POST data) and finally send the SQL request

Comment: okay thanks but i don't understand the part with the    //... fill your table ... 
  how can i make the data to a request?

Comment: Could you make a example with the ajax db post? i know how to insert things into a db, but i have never done it with Json and i don't know how to place the values from the table into the Database, and should i use mysql instead?

Comment: You need an example of SQL and PHP.. First create the script to save a record in the DB.  Then, we will make the request with AJAX.

Comment: okay so now i have pulled the data into the script https://gist.github.com/kris914g/f63a869791fbf16b79d9 what should i do now?

Comment: but how can i do the saving part

Comment: -_- 

Try a bit by yourself? https://gist.github.com/kris914g/528e529a04f90035bd45

   I took more than every other questions to answer here and you do not even try by yourself, informations, google, tutorials

Comment: i will try to figurate something out. Thanks for the help!